# Retrieving all owned_tags for a taggable in acts_as_taggable on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have two models: `User` and `Post`

`User` `acts_as_tagger` and `Post` `acts_as_taggable`

I use the following method to create tagging by a user:

```
@user.tag(@post, :with =>"tag1, tag2, tag3", :on => :tags )
```

All users can tag a post...

and now I want to retrieve all tags for `@post`:

```
@post.tag_list is empty!
```

`@post.owned_tags_on(@user, :tags)` outputs all taggings by a specific user id! But I need tags from all users.

Can someone tell me how to do so?

Thanks

Farnaz

Comment: I can't find documentation of `acts_as_tagger` (only for `acts_as_taggable`). I see syntax for adding tags along the lines of `@post.tag_list.add("Awful")`, but not syntax like you described. Can you link to the gem you're using?

Comment: I am using: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/

Comment: the syntax you have used in your comment does not save the tagger id. it sets them all to NULL

Answer (score 0):

`@post.tags` should return all tags for `@post`